# Is calling FIrst and then Skip(1) on IAsyncEnumerable OK?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iasyncenumerable

I have an `IAsyncEnumerable` where I need to store all the results in some DB, but I also need to apply some special processing to the first item. I did it this way:

```cs
var someAsyncEnumerable = GetSomeAsyncEnumerable(cancellationToken);

var firstValue = await someAsyncEnumerable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

if (firstValue is not null)
{
   // log something about first value
   await HandleItem(fitstValue);
}

await foreach(var value in someAsyncEnumerable.Skip(1).WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
{
   await HandleItem(value);
}

private async Task HandleItem(Item item) 
{
   // store item in DB
}
```

With code like this I'm getting a warning:

> Possible multiple enumeration

I wonder, is this just a warning that I can entirely ignore in this case, or is my usage of the enumerable wrong?

Let's assume that my `IAsyncEnumerable` shouldn't be enumerated twice, because it's inefficient, or even breaking.

Comment: Given your last sentence, your usage is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wonder, is this just a warning that I can entirely ignore in this case, or is my usage of the enumerable wrong?

"Wrong" is a strong word - but it could certainly cause problems. You're enumerating the result twice, which is fine in some cases, and problematic in others.

As you've said:

> Let's assume that my IAsyncEnumerable shouldn't be enumerated twice, because it's inefficient, or even breaking.

... then yes, you've got a problem. Because you absolutely *are* triggering enumeration twice.

It would be better to enumerate the sequence once, keeping track of whether you're looking at the first item or not and acting accordingly:

```cs
var someAsyncEnumerable = GetSomeAsyncEnumerable(cancellationToken);
bool first = true;
await foreach (var value in someAsyncEnumerable)
{
   if (first)
   {
       // Special handling of value
       ...
       // For subsequent loop iterations, skip this bit
       first = false;
   }
   else
   {
       await HandleItem(value);    
   }
}
```

Note that here I've assumed that you want an entirely different path for the first item. If you actually just want to do *extra* work beforehand, you don't need the `else` block:

```cs
var someAsyncEnumerable = GetSomeAsyncEnumerable(cancellationToken);
bool first = true;
await foreach (var value in someAsyncEnumerable)
{
   if (first)
   {
       // Special handling of value
       ...
       // For subsequent loop iterations, skip this bit
       first = false;
   }
   // Regardless of whether this is the first iteration or not,
   // handle the item.
   await HandleItem(value);    
}
```

Alternatively, you *could* potentially expand the `foreach` loop yourself into `MoveNext` calls etc, but that's a bit more error-prone.

Comment: Right, the `first` variable and conditional inside of `foreach` is what I wanted to avoid. I hoped that `First` and then `Skip` would do some magic internally in the runtime so that it wouldn't be enumerated twice. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @mnj nope, there's no special magic for that scenario

Comment: @mnj: No, they absolutely don't, and it wouldn't make sense for them too. Suppose you have a method of `IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers()` - that *should* give different results if you enumerate it multiple times.